# Searching for \ and | characters in a string in PostgreSQL

Tags: regex, postgresql

I am trying to search for a string that contains either a \  or / or a | character stored in column of a table.

so for an example:

I have a table called medication .

lets say the column of this medication table is brand

the brand table has some string values like:

```
abcef\ang\el
mghi/profe|ssional
bb/er|sup/er
```

i want to search for any record in the medication table that has either a  \, /, or a | Character. As you can see there can be numerous occurences of these characters

If there is a match then I need to return the entire record.

Can anyone help and suggest if he following is correct or show a better way. Please note I plan to use regex as this is big table, and I am going this table with other tables as well.

this is what i did:

```
select m.brand 
from medication m 
where m.brand ~ '.*[\|\\\/].*'
```

I was trying to use regex_matches also but did not have any luck using it in where clause

also I tried this

```
select regex_matches(m.brand,'.*[\\\|\/].*',) from medication m
```

but i get kernel errors

any help would be appreciated

thanks
jay

Comment: `where m.brand ~ '.*[\|\\\/].*'` looks like it would work, what went wrong when you tried?

Comment: "\" doesn't passing through

Answer (score 1):

Following code works:

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM foo;
┌────────────────────┐
│         a          │
╞════════════════════╡
│ abcef\ang\el       │
│ mghi/profe|ssional │
│ bb/er|sup/er       │
└────────────────────┘
(3 rows)

SELECT * FROM foo WHERE a LIKE ANY (ARRAY['%|%','%\\%','%/%']);
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE a like '%|' OR a LIKE '%\\%' OR a LIKE '%/%';
or 
postgres=# SELECT * FROM foo WHERE a ~ '[\\|/]';
┌────────────────────┐
│         a          │
╞════════════════════╡
│ abcef\ang\el       │
│ mghi/profe|ssional │
│ bb/er|sup/er       │
└────────────────────┘
(3 rows)
```

Attention - it can depends on PostgreSQL version. For some older PostgreSQL a "\" is a special symbol - and needs special escaping. But on 9.x line it should to work.